# Flutter Build iOS Xcode 12.2 Error in MacOS Big Sur VirtualBox

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, virtualbox, macos-big-sur

I'm a beginner Flutter developer here. I have already developed my Flutter app and would like to publish an iOS app of it to the App Store. But it gives out the error when I run the "flutter build ios" or "flutter build ipa" command. Error message here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWNgL.png

I'm using Windows 10 now and running a MacOs Big Sur 11.0.1 in a Virtualbox. I am currently using Xcode 12.2 to open the Runner. When I open the Runner, it gives me this error message in the Signing and Capabilities tab. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvGU5.png )

I have already created the Identifier, created an app in the App Store Connect, and also created a provisioning profile for it.

App bundle identifier - https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1sXv.png

App Store Connect - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ujP.png

Provisioning Profile - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEhyo.png

Can you guys help me out with this and advise what exactly am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let's try installing old version `cocoapods`.

->Uninstall `cocoapods`

->install old version cocoapods (e.g. 1.8.0)`sudo gem install cocoapods --version '=1.8.0' -n /usr/local/bin`

->flutter clean

->pub get

->run your project (iOS simulator)
```

Comment: I still get the error here

No profiles for 'com.xxx' were found: Xcode
    couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
    'com.xxx'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable
    to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass
    -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project
    'Runner')

Could it be something to to with the Xcode version?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `flutter doctor` from terminal? Run that and see if it all checks out.

After that, I recommend you try to build the default sample counter App.
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#create-and-run-a-simple-flutter-app

- If you can't `flutter build ios` on the test app, then you've isolated to your setup.
- If you can build the sample app, then it's an issue specific to your app.

You might also try building using on online service like codemagic, which has  a free tier: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive-with-codemagic-cli-tools

see also: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos for `flutter doc` examples.